# What's a British equivalent to the more American expression 'Kiss my ass'?

Tags: phrases, idioms, slang, translation, offensive-language

I have the feeling that 'kiss my ass' isn't as widely used in the UK as it is in the US.

I'm looking for a more British sounding equivalent.

Comment: If you're asking Brits to provide a "translation" which doesn't include *ass/arse* then some indication of how the expression is used in its original American English would definitely be beneficial. Currently, the question assumes the expression is well-known, and yet acknowledges that it might not be in its target audience.

Comment: From my experience as a consumer of much British media, I believe they say it just as much as Americans.

Comment: @GeorgeCapote Well, ***I*** certainly don't. And just because media companies seem to use it doesn't mean that they (or I, or anyone else) knows how it is used in the US and what a "native" expression might be.

Comment: _Kiss my ass_, Andrew.  But actually, do you think it'd be appropriate for me to edit the question with a description of how I think the expression is used in the US?

Comment: what? no Cockney rhyming slang??

Comment: My feeling is that it's said less here in the UK than in the US. But then, my knowledge of the latter comes mainly from the media. I can't think of a common equivalent in an "X my Y" form. To be frank, I think most Brits are more likely to just say "fuck you".

Comment: I've flagged as unclear because I think that you need to provide the details @AndrewLeach mentioned for this to be properly answerable. There's never going to be two phrases that mean *exactly* the same, so I think you need to give an example context at the very least and preferably more.

Answer (score 3):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kiss%20my%20ass%2C%20kiss%20my%20arse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckiss%20my%20ass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckiss%20my%20arse%3B%2Cc0) shows that the expression is used in the UK too also in the version 'kiss my arse' since the 40s.

> Kiss my arse!  (British & Australian taboo!) also Kiss my ass! *(American & Australian Taboo)*
>
> - something that you say in order to tell someone that you will not do what they want you to.
>
>   *He asked for money, and I told him he could kiss my arse.*

Probably : Forget it!!! Is a more British way to express the concept.

Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Kiss+my+ass!

Comment: I think the vast majority of Brits will *say* "arse" even if they read or write "ass".